# Ansible: Using node anchors and merge keys split over different yaml files

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm having difficulty getting Ansible to work with YAML merge keys and node anchors and wondering whether these can work when they are in different files and what might be an alternative approach.

I'm attempting to define default data structure (see `vars/default/vars.yaml`) and merge this in to a more specific version (see `vars/specific/vars.yaml`) though these are in different files:

For example,

```
playbook/
├── my_playbook.yaml
├── tasks
│   └── example.yaml
└── vars
    ├── default
    │   └── vars.yaml
    └── specific
        └── vars.yaml
```

The contents of the files which recreates this issue are as follows:

**playbook/my_playbook.yaml**

```
---
- hosts:            "local"
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: "tasks/example.yaml"
```

**playbook/tasks/example.yaml**

```
- name: include default and specific
  include_vars:
    file: "{{item}}"
  with_items:
      - "default/vars.yaml"
      - "specific/vars.yaml"
```

**playbook/vars/default/vars.yaml**

```
---
process_settings: &default_process_settings
    kill_timeout:      "10"
    log_retention:     "5"
    retry_times:       "3"
    alert_email:       "process.alert@testsite.com",
    deploy_server:     "http://testsite.com:8000"
```

**playbook/vars/specific/vars.yaml**

```
---
process_settings:
    <<: *default_process_settings
    heartbeat_rate:    "5"
```

It's in this last file that *appears* to be causing the problem. When I run the playbook:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook/my_playbook.yaml
```

I get the following cryptic error:

```
TASK [include default and specific] ***********************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=default/vars.yaml)
failed: [127.0.0.1] (item=specific/vars.yaml) => {"ansible_facts": {}, "ansible_included_var_files": [], "changed": false, "failed": true, "item": "specific/vars.yaml", "message": "Syntax Error while loading YAML.\n\n\nThe error appears to have been in 'True': line 4, column 9, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\n(could not open file to display line)\nexception type: <class 
'yaml.composer.ComposerError'>\nexception: found undefined alias\n  in \"<unicode string>\", line 4, column 9"}
```

It seems that Ansible can pick up variable from different YAML files but YAML references using node anchors and merge keys will only work when in the same file. From a purely YAML perspective, this is reasonable enough I suppose.

How can I get this to work? Is there another approach that can achieve this aim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm having difficulty getting Ansible to work with YAML merge keys and node anchors and wondering whether these can work when they are in different files and what might be an alternative approach.

Merge keys and node anchors cannot be used across files. They are only useful within a single YAML document.

> I get the following cryptic error:

"exception: found undefined alias" seems to accurately describe the problem.

> Can anyone suggest whether/how this can work or whether there's another approach that can achieve this aim?

You can use the `combine` filter:

```
process_settings: "{{ default_process_settings|combine({'heartbeat_rate':    '5'}) }}"
```

The same, but perhaps easier to read (and easier to write, especially if you've got more than a single key):

```
override_process_settings:
    heartbeat_rate:    "5"

process_settings: "{{ default_process_settings|combine(override_process_settings) }}"
```

Comment: A nice solution. A bit of a shame that the solution can't be generic enough to use the same variable name (i.e. `process_settings: "{{ process_settings|combine({'heartbeat_rate':    '5'}) }}"`) without causing recursion errors, but I guess this is the trade off for allowing late evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

Although the [merge key document](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html) doesn't say anything about multiple documents

But the [YAML specification is very explicit about the use of aliases](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2786196):

> It is an error for an alias node to use an anchor that does not previously occur in the document

So an alias is invalid **if it is in the same file, but referencing a different document**, and you try to reference an anchor in a document in a different file, so that is not valid either.